# Bookmark persistence

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I am trying to create a bookmark with workflow foundation and SQL server DB.The codeActivity got executed without error, but there is no record created in System.Activities.DurableInstancing.InstancesTable.

Please let me know if you know what may cause this problem, thanks much.

```
  public sealed class Wait4InputDataActivity<T> : NativeActivity
{
    public InArgument<string> BookMarkName { get; set; }
    public OutArgument<T> OutData { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        // get Text input's runtime value
        string bookMarkName = context.GetValue(this.BookMarkName);
        // bookMark has return value, add callback function
        context.CreateBookmark(bookMarkName, new BookmarkCallback(AfterContinue));
    }

    protected override bool CanInduceIdle
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void AfterContinue(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object value)
    {
        context.SetValue(OutData, (T)value);
    }


}
```

Comment: How are you hosting the WF? Is the hosting environment correctly configured to persist workflow instances on idle? Does the WF really become idle?

Comment: WorkflowApplication;                                                           WorkflowApplication application = new WorkflowApplication(activity, paramsData);
            SqlWorkflowInstanceStore instanceStore = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(connstr);
            application.InstanceStore = instanceStore;
            application.PersistableIdle = arg => { return PersistableIdleAction.Unload; };
            application.Idle = a => { Console.WriteLine("Workflow stopped..."); };
            application.Run();

Comment: Does it become idle, i.e. do you see the "Workflow stopped..." output?

Comment: I ran the SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreSchema, and the SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreLogic for DB persistence... is there anything else I need to configure?

Comment: Yes.  Console.WriteLine("Workflow stopped...") get executed.

Comment: Workflow stopped...  after that it was aborted...
application.Aborted = x =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Aborted");
                autoResetEvent.Set();

            };

Comment: It was a run time problem. It was solved by using a normal connection string, thanks for the reply.